# Shuffle a integer using recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x

A recursive function that takes an integer and shuffles it. Shuffle one digit from the front and one digit from the back, then the second from the front and the second from the back, and so on until the shuffled number is the same as that original.

For example, 123456 would print as 162534 or 130 would print as 103. Any help would be appreciated.

On the string, it's easy, need the suggestion for integer.

```
A = '130'

def shuffle(A):
    if len(A) <= 2:
        return A
    return (A[0] + A[-1]) + shuffle(A[1:-1])
```

Output: 103

Comment: But don't you need a *random* element here? Or do you want to "shuffle" deterministically in some way?

Comment: 1) Convert the int to a string; 2) Do it for the string; 3) convert back. Is that cheating?

Comment: It looks like you want to each time take the first and last element?

Comment: Why does it need to be a recursive function?

Comment: Presumably because this is homework, and for some reason CS-101 instructors are obsessed with shoehorning recursion into places it doesn't belong :P

Comment: @blorgbeard I think you're probably right, but I thought it best to ask since it's in the title but nobody asked :)

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yeah, I don't know why so many instructors go out of their way to assign "here's this paradigm case of exactly when you should definitely use `for`, so write it with recursion/`while`/whatever" when it's really not hard to find actual use cases for those other features.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you are right, I have updated the shuffled logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

convert it to a string?

```
A = 130

def shuffle(A):
    A = str(A)
    if len(A) <= 2:
        return int(A)
    return int((A[0] + A[-1]) + str(shuffle(A[1:-1])))
```

Answer (score 3):

Without converting to a string:

```
def shuffle(x):
    if x < 100:
        return x
    t = x
    l = 0
    while t > 0:
        t //= 10
        l += 1
    a = x // 10 ** (l-1) * 10 ** (l-1)
    b = (x % 10) * 10 ** (l-2)
    return a + b + shuffle((x - a) // 10)
```

and the tests work:

```
>>> shuffle(123456)
162534
>>> shuffle(310)
301
```

Comment: This is awesome! Python 3.x only 'cause of `//`

Comment: @dawg Thanks, yeah in Python 2, you could just use `/` though. p.s. nobody knows I am a cat.

Comment: or `from __future__ import division`

Answer (score 0):

C#

```
public static int testfun(int A)
    {
        string output = "";

        if (A >= 0 && A <= 100000000)
        {
            string input = A.ToString();
            var numchars = input.ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < numchars.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    output += numchars[i/2];
                }
                else
                {
                    output += numchars[numchars.Length - (i/2+1)];
                }
            }

        }
         return Convert.ToInt32(output);

    }
```

Comment: Hi! Can you explain why we are using `i/2`? Can't quite get it...

Answer (score 0):

Iterating `string` and using `slices` with positive and negative index

```
def shuffle(phrase):
  even = 0
  odd = -1
  result = ''
  phrase = str(phrase)

  for n in range(len(phrase)):
    if int(n/2) == n/2:
      result = result + phrase[even]
      even += 1
    else:
      result = result + phrase[odd]
      odd += -1

  return result
```

Answer (score -1):

Java solution for students

```
  int shuffle(int num) {

    String str = String.valueOf(num);
    if (str.length() <= 1) {
        return num;
    }

    char[] firstHalf = str.substring(0,str.length()/2).toCharArray();
    char[] secondHalf = new StringBuilder(str.substring(str.length()/2)).reverse().toString().toCharArray();
    StringBuilder finalStr = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0;i<firstHalf.length;i++) {
        finalStr.append(firstHalf[i]);
        finalStr.append(secondHalf[i]);
    }
    // To handle for odd numbers length of array
    if (secondHalf.length > firstHalf.length) {
        finalStr.append(secondHalf[secondHalf.length - 1]);
    }

    return Integer.parseInt(finalStr.toString());
}
```

Comment: bona fide intent, but out of scope apparently